# Jupyterhub - how to select the installed python version

Tags: python, jupyterhub

Jupyterhub uses a specific python version when creating new notebooks.
I can't find out where to set this version.

I installed anaconda on my ubuntu and created a link between python and anaconda's distribution

```
usr/bin$ ls -l pyt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Feb  9 18:34 python -> /usr/anaconda/bin/python
```

which works :

```
:/usr/bin$ python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But when I use jupyterhub the notebooks are created using another installation of python. I see on the jupyter's terminal that the correct python version is accessed through the terminal so. It is only on the notebooks that the version is wrong.

Should I create a specific kernel ? 
Or can I set up an env variable to make jupyterhub use the anacondas' python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use your python version, then you have to create a new kernel. Technically your specific kernel.
I'll attach a website which explains how you can undergo this process:
[Install known Python version](http://zonca.github.io/2015/10/use-own-python-in-jupyterhub.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Anaconda created my kernel in [~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels] and not [~/.ipython/kernels/python3] as written on the blog, but it lead me to the right way :)

Comment: @romainjouin glad I could help. :)