# change python version in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using jupyter notebook and jupyter lab through jupyter hub.
Currently, the python version recognized by jupyter is 3.6.8.
[image]

I want to set the python version to 3.7.3.

The python version installed on the server is as follows. (/usr/bin/python*)
[image]
[image]

The jupyter notebook kernel is set as follows in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json

If you change the argv path to '/usr/bin/python3' or '/usr/bin/python3.7', the kernel is busy and the connection is not made. TT
It works well only when argv path is '/usr/bin/python 3.6'.

[image]

- Setting Code

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

`sudo pip3 install ipykernel`

`sudo jupyter kernelspec install-self`

Answer (score 0):

as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299071/jupyterhub-how-to-select-the-installed-python-versionhttps://) says, you need to create a new kernel and [this website](https://zonca.dev/2015/10/use-own-python-in-jupyterhub.html) shows how to do it

Comment: Thank you for sharing good information. 
However, the Python version is still 3.6.8.

The location of kernel.json that jupyter is currently importing is [/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels]. 
But if you add the kernel according to the website you mentioned, the kernel is created in [/root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels]. 
So Python is still set to 3.6.8.

Comment: My server has 2 ipython paths so I tried them all.
If set to ```~/anaconda3/bin/ipython kernel install --user --name python37```, kernel.json is created in [/root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels],
When accessing with a user account, a permission error occurs and the kernel bursts altogether. 
Error : Permission denied: '/root/anaconda3/bin/python3.7

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinstalling the below packages. thank you.

````
pip3 install tornado==5.1.1
pip3 install notebook==5.7.4```
````